# python django application - not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

This is a initial tutorial of python django. Article is my app name. django_tes is my project. When I load the project to server/hello/ I get the following error:

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL: servername/hello/
>
> Django Version: 1.6.2 Python Version: 2.7.5 Installed Applications:
>   ('django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles',  'article')
>   Installed Middleware:
>   ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')
>
> Traceback: File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in
>   get_response
>     114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "/cygdrive/d/fraservalley/django/django_tes/article/views.py" in hello
>     10.    name = "Mike"
>
> Exception Type: TypeError at /hello/ Exception Value: not all
>   arguments converted during string formatting

I am completely new to python and django. I can understand that in views.py %s corresponds to name string then why the error?

CAn anyone please help.

---

**views.py from article folder**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context
from models import Article
# Create your views here.
#views are representations of what the user might see

def hello(request):
   name = "Mike"
   html = "<html><body>Hi %s this seem to work!</body></html>" % name
   return HttpResponse(html)
'''
def hello_template(request):
   name = "Mike"
   t = get_template('hello.html')
   html = t.render(Context({'name': name}))
   return HttpResponse(html)
'''
```

**urls.py from django_tes folder**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from article import views
#from django.contrib import admin
#admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'django_tes.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^hello/$','article.views.hello'),
    #url(r'^hello_template/$','article.views.hello_template'),
    #url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

**models.py from django_tes folder**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Article(models.Model): #helps to create representation of data
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   body = models.TextField()
   pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
   likes = models.IntegerField()

   def __unicode__(self):
      return self.title
```

**settings.py from django_tes folder**

```
"""
Django settings for django_tes project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'article',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_tes.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_tes.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),)

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'D:/fraservalley/django/django_tes/storage.db',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Also, please include your entire stack trace?

Comment: @warunsl added the stack trace

Comment: The error has something to do with the string formatting used in the `html` variable declaration. Can you replace it with `html = "<html><body>Hi {} this seem to work!</body></html>".format(name)` and check?

Comment: @warunsl that dint work

Comment: Can you try `html = "<html><body>Hi %s this seem to work!</body></html>" % (name,)`?